# Criteria query from HQL and exclude certain column

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1, named-query

I have this named query :

```
select person from Person person , Citizen citizen 
where person.id = citizen.id ;
```

And my entity person is of the following way

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PERSON")
    public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PERSONID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long personId;
...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Set<Citizen> citizen= new HashSet<Citizen>();
    }
```

And the entity Citizen

```
@Entity
public class Citizen{
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PERSONID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long personId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSONID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Person person;

    private String name;
    private String secondname;
    private String phone;
}
```

The idea is to execute the named query , to retrieve a person object with a list of citizens that contains each one , just with name attribute in the response , excluding phone and secondname attributes. Is there any way to do this with HQL or Criteria ?

Comment: AFAIK A named query, or any HQL query, will return a full-blown `Citizen` object with all its fields.  Is there some reason why you don't want certain fields?

Comment: you can create a "lite" Citizen entity containing only the fields you want and have that as a property of Person but that's not what you want right?

Comment: I need in my response just the name of the citizen to form a json  of citizen

Comment: define if using JPA or Hibernate API. Untag things like Hibernate-Criteria if using JPA. JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs allow control over what gets returned, hence allowing partial objects